# iOS: xCode not recognizing new class methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, header-files

For some reason new methods that I add to a custom NSObject class aren't being recognized in other files that import the class. The old ones are still being autofilled, but the new ones get a "no known class method for selector". All methods in the class are defined as class methods (+).

I've cleaned and tried rebuilding, and I've tried restarting xCode. I can't figure out whats wrong. Anyone experience this before?

```
@interface SongMethods : NSObject

+(NSMutableArray *)asdf;
```

And then to call it

```
#import "SongMethods.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()
@property ViewType billboardType;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

-(void)someMethod
{
[SongMethods asdf];
}
```

Comment: header files would have nothing to do with a runtime error. show some code.

Comment: are you #import "custom class.h"?

Comment: Show the line how you call this method?

Comment: Its not a runtime error. It pops up as soon as I put in the method name. And of course I've imported the file (otherwise the other methods wouldn't have worked. I'll include code, but its not going to help.

Comment: have you actually implemented the asdf method in SongMethods.m?

Comment: Are there any other errors e.g. in SongMethods.h / .m file?

Comment: No I figured it out. See my answer below. Silly and I'm not exactly sure how it happened.

Answer (score 4):

The file was referenced from duplicate locations for some reason, and the one being imported in the other classes was not the same as the one I was editing in the navigator.

Comment: Yip! I dunno how I did it. I'm an impressive lad.

Comment: I had a similar issue where I had imported the files. Then removed references and imported another set into another location within the project. Xcode was still reading the old set and not the new ones I imported. For anyone else, check to see that you don't have two copies of those files within your Xcode project. If you do delete both sets of the files, remove them from the Xcode source list and reimport them into Xcode after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove the entire project derived data folder.

Answer (score 0):

To create class method, you need to first introduce that method in your .h file:

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

// Note: + sign is for class method and - sign for instance method
+ (BOOL)returnYesPlease;

@end
```

Then add implementation of your method in .m file:

MyClass.m

```
@implementation MyClass

+ (BOOL)returnYesPlease {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

---

To use class method in MyClass, you need to import header file first in .h file:

MyOtherClass.h

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyOtherClass : NSObject

@end
```

To call that class method in .m file:

```
@implementation MyOtherClass

- (void)doSomething {
    BOOL yesVar = [MyClass returnYesPlease];
}

@end
```